# Missing, Duplicate declaration in current scope

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently writing a program to analyze some data, and my Debugger is throwing the "Duplicate Declaration in Current Scope"  error, highlighting "Dim rTickers As Range". I cannot find a duplicate anywhere in here. Is there some other reason I could be getting this error? Thanks for your time.

```
Sub TSV_Ticker()
    'Create Dictionary To get Unique Values From Column A
    Dim dTickers As New Dictionary
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To Rows.Count
        On Error Resume Next
        dTickers.Add (Cells(i, 1).Value), CStr(Cells(i, 1).Value)
    Next

    'Create The Ticker And Sum Column Headers
    Range("J1").Value = "<Sum>"
    Range("I1").Value = "<Ticker>"

    'Define where we will be putting our keys
    Dim uTickers As Range
    Set uTickers = Range("I2")
    'Convert Keys into array for syntax reasons
    aTickers = dTickers.Keys
    'Resize the range so it will fit the array
    Set rTickers = rTickers.Resize(UBound(aTickers), 1)
    'Put array into range, verticaly
    rTickers.Value = Application.Transpose(aTickers)

    'Define Range of column A
    Dim rTickers As Range
    Set rTickers = Range("A2:A" & ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    Dim TSV As Long

    'Defining some Date Variables (Column B)
    Dim fDate As Integer
    Dim eDate As Integer
    Dim rDates As Range
    Set rDates = Range("B2:B" & ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

    'And The Open / Close Variables (Colums C&F)
    Dim vOpen As Double
    Dim Vclose As Double
    Dim Delta As Double
    Dim pDelta As Double

    'Adding Some Columns
    sht.Range("J1").EntireColumn.Insert
    Range("J1").Value = "Yearly Change"
    sht.Range("K1").EntireColumn.Insert
    Range("K1").Value = "Percent Change"

    For Each Cell In rTickers
        'Searching our range that we put the Array in for matching Values
        Set t = rTickers.Find(Cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not t Is Empty Then
            'add column G's value to corresponding I value
            Cells(t.Row, 10).Value = Cells(t.Row, 10).Value + Cells(Cell.Row, 7).Value
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Comment out that culprit `Dim` row, then in the next line click on `rTickers`, press Shit+F2...and you will know.

Comment: Hit CTRL+F, choose **Entire Project** and search for `rTickers`.  You could add the line `Option Explicit` at the top of the module, to help identify this and some of your other issues.  Also, `On Error Resume Next` should be generally avoided, especially during troubleshooting.  In this case, you are "turning on" error-ignoring **1,048,575** times (and not "turning it off" at all)

Comment: It's a common usage to put all your `Dim` at the beginning of your sub. Might be easier to trace them.

Comment: You've used `rTickers` in a line above your declaration.

Comment: There appear to be several variables declared that are unused, and others referenced that are undeclared.  As suggested, [using `Option Explicit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/option-explicit-statement) as the first line of the module will help you sort through and get organized. See also **How to create a [mcve]** as well as these [**VBA Debugging** tips](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) from Chip Pearson.

Comment: @Ashleedawg the reason I had On Error Resume Next on in this case, I needed a list with unique values. In order to populate my dictionary without grabbing the duplicates I believe I needed that, Is there a more efficient way to go about that?

Comment: Thanks @Rory that was the ticket. (They needed to be uTickers)

Comment: And I assume you didn't use `Option Explicit` as what ashlee pointed so at the first instance `rTickers` is used it is created so the `Dim rTickers As Range` will then throw the `Duplicate Declaration`.

Answer (score 1):

As commented, without using `Option Explicit` variables are created at the first instance.
So in your code, `rTickers` is already created when this below line is executed:

```
Set rTickers = rTickers.Resize(UBound(aTickers), 1)
```

That being said, below line will give you a compile error:

```
Dim rTickers As Range
```

[image]

because `rTickers` variable has already been created.
I'll post this as answer for others reference.
But if Rory or Ashlee wish to add their answers, I'll delete mine :).